# Is it possible to get body from System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Is it possible to get body from System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response?

Content type is text/html. I want to place it into string var for later usage.

I can access headers but struggling to get the body. I can't see any properties in this class which return the body.

Comment: Are you sending the response (at server) or receiving the response  (at client)?

Comment: I'm sending the response (at server)

Comment: Have you tried getting the response in [EndRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.endrequest?view=netframework-3.5)?